# How to convert relative gravitational force to coordinates

Tags: algorithm, mapping, coordinate

I have a question. 
I have N objects and N x N matrix M. Each entry M(i, j) contains (a kind of) relative gravitational force indicating how strongly i pulls j toward it (or inversely pull it away from it).
I want to place these N objects on a two-dimensional R x R plane by assigning a coordinate to each object.

Is there an algorithm/method that does this? There must be some commonly methods used in astrophysics, physics, chemistry, etc.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: What kind of coordinate are you after?

Comment: Does something keep you from just placing the objects randomly or arbitrarily?  Eg, are you looking for a placement that is statically or dynamically stable?

Comment: If you're trying to perform a gravitational simulation, then this is called an n-body problem or n-body simulation; even in 2-d it probably won't have an analytical solution if n is greater than 2.  The [N-body simulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-body_simulation) article in Wikipedia discusses how to derive/implement a numeric solution to the problem.

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot I think N-body simulation is more interested in dynamic aspect. Here the OP is interested in static value. So I don't think they are the same.

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot  I think it is pretty clear. What part you don't understand?

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot But you know the gravitational force between every pair of object. Gravitational force is a function of mass and distance. This is very similar to case where you know distance between every pair and you want to place them in a 3D co-ordinate system so that distances are consistent (except, here we also need to find mass).

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot See equation for gravitation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_law_of_universal_gravitation . The OP did not say the objects are moving, so no velocity.

Answer (score 0):

You are interested in assigning co-ordinates (xi,yi,zi) and mass (mi) to each object such that gravitational force is consistent, right?

Consider 8 points at a time. You have a total of 32 unknowns and 28 equations. You can assume that first point is at origin and second point on x axis. That means, you will have 28 unknown and 28 equations.

So, first device and algorithm to solve for 8 points at a time. Then incrementally add one point at each iteration.

**===Walkthrough===**

Consider you are given n points in D dimensions. You only have distances between the points, but not the co-ordinates. Goal is to find co-ordinates for each point.

If D=1, you need to consider only two (+1) points at a time. Place first point at origin. Place second point on the positive side of origin. You can place third point in relation to origin, but place it right or left of it depending on the distance to first point and so on...

If D=2, place point 1 at origin, point to on positive side on x axis, third point on positive side of y axis depending on distance. From fourth point onward, you can use any two placed points to place the next and use any other point to refine the options (there will be two options).

Similar with D=3. Place first three points on xy plane (z=0) for all three. Next, place 4th point ofn postive part of z axist. And so on.

**Coming back to gravity:**
Your problem is complicated because you cannot exactly place mass at the origin. So you would need more than 5 points to place them. As I have shown above, you need at most 8 points though.

In case your mass are all equal, you can calculate distance (~inverse of gravity) and apply the case when D=3.

Comment: You can assume that first point is at origin, second point on x axis, third point has z=0.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff which leaves us with 28 equations and 27 unknowns?

Comment: @JanDvorak - Yes, system could be unsolvable

Comment: @JanDvorak You can always reduce the the number of points to use. In a truly Cartesian case it is pretty straightforward, but mass in this case make everything difficult. If the values are consistent, you can still use 28 equations and 27 unknowns, and still be okay.

Comment: Yes, I am interested in assigning coordinates (x, y) on 2D plane. The values are static, and i don't consider mass. Another complexity is M(i,j) != M(j,i) (M is asymmetric matrix).

Comment: @user2316950 I have updated my answer. See the walk through for case (D=3) when mass are out of picture.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, given that we know the n*n distances between n objects, how to obtain their positions?

```
1. Put the first one, say a, at (0,0)
2. Put the second one b at ( |b-a|, 0 )
3. For the third one c, it is at the one of the two intersections of the two circles:
     |p-a|=|c-a| and |p-b|=|c-b|. 
     Solve this system of quadratic equations using the well-known formula, choose
     either of the solutions as the position of c.
4. For any other points p, do the same thing as we're done for c, but choose one of the
     two solutions that is consistent with the distance |p-c|. And check the distance
     between p and all previous points. If the check fails, return with failure.
```